# mongoDB iterate over keys of document & sum values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm very new to the  MongoDb. With that said, my csv file data is as below which are about yearly  expenses.

```
{"Name": "Aruba",
   "Code": "ABW",
   "Type": "Country",
   "IndicatorName": "Military_expenditure",
   "1900": 0,
   "1961": 1,
   "1962": 0,
   "1963": 0,
   "1964": 0,
   "1965": 0,
   "1966": 0,
   "1967": 0,
   "1968": 0,
   "1969": 0
}, {
   "Name": "Afghanistan",
   "Code": "AFG",
   "Type": "Country",
   "IndicatorName": "Military_expenditure",
   "1900": 0,
   "1961": 100,
   "1962": 0,
   "1963": 0,
   "1964": 0,
   "1965": 0,
   "1966": 0,
   "1967": 0,
   "1968": 0,
   "1969": 0
}
```

However, I need to get the summation of

1. Total yearly expenses, that is

> Aruba=1 >>  (1900=**0** + 1961=**1**......+ 1969=**0**} Afghanistan =
>   100 >> (1900=**0** + 1961=**100**......+ 1969=**0**}

2. Total Expense of the countries =101

> Aruba (1900=**0** + 1961=**1**......+ 1969=**0**} +
>   Afghanistan(1900=**0** + 1961=**100**......+ 1969=**0**}

can someone please help to do the above calculations in MongoDb

However, I have written query to get the year wise summation

```
db.MiltryExpenditure.aggregate([

 { $match: { "Type":"Country" } },

 {$group:{_id : null,
 1969: { $sum: { "$toDouble":"$1969" }}
, _id : null,
 1960: { $sum: { 

"$toDouble":"$1960" }},
}}
])
```

But I don't know how to get the Total summation of the countries, as well as if theirs a normalize method to get the country wise summation , that would be much appreciated.

Please Help...

Comment: Do you only have those years or more random n no.of years ? Also how many other fields do you've ? maybe this has to be or can be easily done using language code..!!

Comment: I have the years from 1900-2018 & 265 rows(countries), I have to accomplish this task using mongo commands

Comment: Do you've duplicate documents with `"Name": "Afghanistan"` or `"Name": "Aruba"` like that ?

Comment: no, i do not have any duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([{ $match: { "Type": "Country" } },
{ $project: { _id: 0, Code: 0, IndicatorName: 0, Type: 0 } },
{
    $addFields: {
        onlyYears: {
            $filter: {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                as: "item",
                cond: { $ne: ["$$item.k", 'Name'] }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        Name: 1, count: {
            $reduce: {
                input: '$onlyYears',
                initialValue: 0,
                in: { $add: ["$$value", {"$toDouble": "$$this.v"}] }
            }
        }
    }
},
{ $group: { _id: '', count: { $sum: '$count' }, data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } }
])
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "",
    "count" : 101.0,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Aruba",
            "count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Afghanistan",
            "count" : 100.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this gives me an syntax error saying that $add only support numeric or data type not strings,
I believe this error comes because CSV data uploaded to the collection recognize the expense value as string.

can you please help to include the conversion from string to double as well

Comment: @Udk : Updated code w.r.t. string values for expenses!!

Comment: Do you mean `Name` inside `data` ? Can you give me your result here..

Comment: This is the result I get 
{ "_id" : "", "count" : 3240672793.3, "data" : [ { "Name" : "0", "count" : 1 }, { "Name" : "0", "count" : 3240672792.3 } ] }

Comment: @Udk : Everything work fine for me for the given documents in question, Can you check if you've any field names vary in your actual docs for `Name` field..

Comment: I have different expense values for the years in actual CSV as i have posted few only in the question. So the count is right only the Name is not visible

Comment: @Udk : that's fine count is working fine, Can you check for names what is the issue..

Comment: Name doesnot give any precise error , just sets to 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205338/discussion-between-udk-and-srinivasy).

Comment: @Udk : try my answer in chat room

Answer (score 2):

[$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) allows you to convert your [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) object into an array of keys and values. Then you can apply [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) on that array to get only those pairs representing years. Once the data set is limited to years you can run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) in order to execute [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) on every year separately:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            years: { 
                $filter: { 
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }, 
                    cond: { $and: [ { $gte: [ "$$this.k", "1900" ] }, { $lte: [ "$$this.k", "2020" ] } ] } 
                } 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$years"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$years.k",
            total: { $sum: "$years.v" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id: 1 }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JWZfkijpBOK)

Grouping by country is easier, you can run [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) twice (to sum up all years by doc and then inside `$group`):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Name: 1,
            years: { 
                $filter: { 
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }, 
                    cond: { $and: [ { $gte: [ "$$this.k", "1900" ] }, { $lte: [ "$$this.k", "2020" ] } ] } 
                } 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$Name",
            total: { $sum: { "$sum": "$years.v" } }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground (2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mXok_cwXiPF)

EDIT: second query can be shortened if there's single document per country (you can get rid of `$group`):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Name: 1,
            Total: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { years: { 
                        $filter: { 
                            input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }, 
                            cond: { $and: [ { $gte: [ "$$this.k", "1900" ] }, { $lte: [ "$$this.k", "2020" ] } ] } 
                        } 
                    } },
                    in: { $sum: "$$years.v" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this,

```
    db.MiltryExpenditure.aggregate(
   [{
        "$match": {
            "Type": "Country"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,

            "1969": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$toDouble": "$1969"
                }
            },

            "1960": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$toDouble": "$1960"
                }
            },

            "totalSummation": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$add": [{
                        "$toDouble": "$1960"
                    }, {
                        "$toDouble": "$1961"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: this gives me an error saying "Syntax error : missing ] after element list

My syntax

db.MiltryExpenditure.aggregate(
[
  {
    "$match": {      "Type": "Country"    }  },
  { "$group": {"_id": null,"1969": { "$sum": {"$toDouble": "$1969" }},
                            "1960": { "$sum": {"$toDouble": "$1960"}},
                         "totalSummation": {"$sum": {"$add": ["$toDouble":"$1960","$toDouble":"$1961" ]}}
   }
 } 
]);

Comment: Corrected answer check now.

Comment: Would it be possible to you to suggest, How could I get the top 10 values from this query